# How to get the number of consumers for a queue in celery

Tags: celery

I need to know how many tasks are reserved by all running consumers.
For a single consumer, this is determined by the **worker_prefetch_multiplier parameter**.
To get the total number, I need to know how many consumers are currently running. How do I find out how many of them there are?

I know that I can do this using
`rabbitmqctl list_queues name consumers`, but how do I do this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
`app.control.inspect().stats()` contains all the necessary information.